# Generate color ramp scale for imported base map in QGIS

Tags: basemap, color-ramp, scale-bar

I have imported a bathymetric layer, showing depth variation around an archipelago, which I'm using as a basemap. I would like to create a scale bar for it, showing max and min recorded depths.

Is it possible to create a colour ramp that would correspond to the colours in the imported bathymetric layer?

I am using QGIS 3.14.